# SQL: Count the values of a column per record

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am stuck on creating a query.

I got a table "videos" with this structure:

```
id | artist | song | hits
```

records are like:

```
1 | Rihanna | Song1 | 400
2 | Rihanna | Song2 | 100
3 | Prince | Song45 | 300
4 | The Police | Song456 | 1000
```

This is my non-working query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT artist, SUM(hits)
FROM videos
ORDER BY hits DESC
```

The result is:

```
Rihanna | 1800
```

But I'd like a result like this:

```
Rihanna | 500
Prince | 300
The Police | 1000
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Add `GROUP BY artist` (before ORDER BY.) No need to do DISTINCT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT artist, SUM(hits) as hitscount
FROM videos
GROUP BY artist
ORDER BY hitscount DESC
```

added suggestions from the comments. thanks!

Comment: I'd add a column alias hitscount, and use that in the order by.

Comment: Is the alias accessible in the order clause then?

Comment: Yes, it is accessible .

Comment: Much better. As a general rule, try to avoid writing the same expression twice. This is easier to write (without errors), to read and to maintain.

Comment: I didn't know if it was possible. It's not possible with every rdbms.

Comment: @aleksv Thanks! This works like a charm, you just made my day!

Comment: It's ANSI SQL, and supported by all major rdbms's.

Comment: then I am confusing something :)